# ReferenceError: window is not defined at new Commerce \node_modules\@chec\commerce.js\dist\commerce.export.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, commerce

I am using the pages router and _app.js (custom app)  https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app

I believe my probles lies here, where I have this inside my _app.js :

import '../globals.css';
import { CartProvider } from '../context/cart';

export default function MyApp ({ Component, pageProps}) {

return (

```
<CartProvider>
  <Component {...pageProps}/>
</CartProvider>
```

);
}

node.js command prompt

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at new Commerce (C:\Users\andre\final-exam-react-project\node_modules\@chec\commerce.js\dist\commerce.export.js:1:399)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./lib/commerce.js:8:16)
```

localhost:3000

Server Error

ReferenceError: window is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

```
lib\commerce.js (3:15) @ eval

  1 | import CommerceSDK from "@chec/commerce.js";
  2 |
> 3 | const client = new CommerceSDK(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CHEC_PUBLIC_API_KEY);
    |               ^
  4 |
  5 | export default client;
```

I was expecting it to run correctly but I encountered this problem

I have also tried running this on my project but does not seem to solve anything
`npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`

Comment: *Please provide more details by editing above question, are you using App router or Pages Router ? Add some details like the above code is Client Side or Server side ? In which component is it used  etc.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that `@chec/commerce.js` isn't amenable to server-side rendering since it's attempting to access `window` (which isn't a thing on the server side).

The easiest option here might be

```
const client = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? new CommerceSDK(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CHEC_PUBLIC_API_KEY) : null;
```

(but then you'll naturally need to check whether `client` is not `null` before using it).

Comment: Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'merchants')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

pages\index.js (10:27) @ commerce

   8 |
   9 | export async function getStaticProps() {
> 10 | const merchant = await commerce.merchants.about()
     |                       ^
  11 | const {data: categories} = await commerce.categories.list()
  12 | const {data: products} = await commerce.products.list()

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw. but now I believe that caused my index.js to crash somehow with the getStaticProps()
How do I check wether client is not null in my index.js file ?

Comment: `if(client !== null)`.